# How to store multiple values with style element in the correct way to database in php?

Tags: php

Hi this is my html .

```
<button class="add-div" value="Add Div"/>
<div class="main" style="top:5%; color:red;" >msg1</div>
```

Here there is a javasript code , that will generate extra div when user clik on button .

The following htl is example out put .

```
<div class="main" style="top:5%; color:red;" >msg1</div>
<div class="main" style="top:15%; color:white;" >msg2</div>
<div class="main" style="top:25%; color:black;" >msg3</div>
<div class="main" style="top:35%; color:green;" >msg4</div>
<div class="main" style="top:45%; color:yellow" >msg5</div>
```

Now we need to store this div content and style to databse. But the thing is that , we need to make this all as one entry in the table .  [Here there are 5 div . So i need to save these 5 contents into one column and the style of these 5 contents in another column ]

the structure of table is `id , div-content , div-style .` 
for the above example the entry is like this

```
1  msg1,msg2,msg3,msg4,msg5      top:5%;coloe:red;,top15%;color:white;,...
```

In normal practice everyone will save the entry in one by one . For example

```
id  div-content  div-style

1    msg1        top:5%; color:red;

2    msg2        top:15%; color:white;

3    msg3        top:25%; color:black;

4    msg4        top:35%; color:green;

5    msg5        top:45%; color:yellow
```

**But in my case i need solution like the following**

```
id    div-content                div-style

1     msg1,msg2,msg3,msg4,msg5   top:5%;coloe:red;,top15%;color:white;,...
```

Now how can i store this value to database . After saving this value i need to take this value from database  and need to get these value in foreach or while loop .Please help .

Comment: sorry i tried many codes and failed . i don't have the copy of that code

Comment: Sorry, but it is completely unclear what you are actually trying to do. What structure, what logic is there in the approach? You write "this div content and style", however there is not one `div` element there are 5. So what _is_ to be stored? Where do the elements come from? Why would one want to store style attributes in a database?

Comment: if there's no code we cannot find the problem and therefore cannot solve it. As this is not a free coding service you will not get a complete code out of nothing.

Comment: @arkascha Hi . Please see my updated question .

Comment: You could store those arrays as json serialized strings, that allows to deserialize and use the arrays again later upon retrieval. Note however that this is considered bad style: it is against the idea of relational databases and certainly will deny the benefits to you: selecting and combining individual entries. Also the performance of the full solution will drop dramatically in performance. Question is: _why_ do you think you have to store things in such a way? What reason should there be that you cannot use a normalized structure?

Comment: because for this , i have no permission to change table structure . Could you please give the working sample code as answer ? . Then every one can see this and i will accept that answer .